# Find and Replace for Named Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason the Replace Function I have in this Macro doesn't if i change the value of the for YTD and YTG to ",9," and ",12," the Macro won't work. Here is what I have.

```
  Sub Rename()
   Dim YTG As String
   Dim YTD As String
   Dim Shiftold As String
   Dim Shitnew As String

i = 1

YTG = "<>YTG"
YTD = "YTD"
Shiftold = "0,0,1"
ShiftNew = "0,12,1"


For Each Name In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If InStr(1, Names(i).RefersTo, YTG) > 0 Then
    Names(i).RefersTo = Replace(Names(i).RefersTo, YTG, YTD)
    End If

    If InStr(1, Names(i).RefersTo, Shiftold) > 0 Then
    Names(i).RefersTo = Replace(Names(i).RefersTo, Shiftold, ShiftNew)
    End If

    i = i + 1
Next Name
End Sub
```

Any thoughts on why the macro doesn't work anymore?

Comment: maybe somebody deleted your named ranges

Comment: you are declaring a loop variable `Name`, but it never gets used.  .... are you sure that your loop is correctly built?

Comment: what is `Names(i)`? you have not declared  `Names`.

Comment: did it ever work?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using `Option Explicit` to force variable declarations, which will catch typos and (most) missing declarations.

`Rename` is a terrible choice of macro name (like `Name` is a bad choice of variable name) because it overlaps with common methods etc. and in this case gives little idea of what is actually going to be affected.

As observed in comments you weren't actually using the `For Each` loop variable. This makes it fairly pointless , but actually would be a much better way of accessing elements of the collection.

Below is my suggested improvements; notice that the comments are talking about how I've changed it, so you should actually add some comments describing real purpose rather than using these.

```
Sub UpdateNamedRanges() ' specific macro title

Dim YTG As String
Dim YTD As String
Dim ShiftOld As String
Dim ShiftNew As String ' corrected
Dim AName As Name   'declared

YTG = "<>YTG"
YTD = "YTD"
ShiftOld = "0,0,1"
ShiftNew = "0,12,1"

For Each AName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    ' use loop variable
    If InStr(1, AName.RefersTo, YTG) > 0 Then
        AName.RefersTo = Replace(AName.RefersTo, YTG, YTD)
    End If

    If InStr(1, AName.RefersTo, ShiftOld) > 0 Then
        AName.RefersTo = Replace(AName.RefersTo, ShiftOld, ShiftNew)
    End If
Next AName

End Sub
```

Comment: I used this exactly as written but just changed the values for the variables to  the following

    `YTG = "B$2,9,1"`
    `YTD = "B$2,12,1"`
    `ShiftOld = "B$4,9,1"`
    `ShiftNew = "B$4,12,1"`

This is in order to shift the month that a named range refers to in order to refer to either a previous year or current year based on a reference cell  B4 or B2 and to a month (Sept,=9 or Dec=12). When this runs I get the following error.

Run-time error '1004'
There's an error in the formula you entered.

Comment: Without knowing what your named ranges have for "ReferTo" values, it would be hard to diagnose the issue. This is a fairly fragile way of doing what you want to do; my answer was only a bit of code clean -up, not how I would necessarily achieve the ultimate intention.